# Is there a way to apply CSS filters to a video embed in IOS?

Tags: css, svg, mobile-safari, twitch, svg-filters

I am trying to apply a **CSS / SVG filter to a custom video embed (twitch API)** and so it works on chrome, edge, and IOS.

Works fine on chrome/edge but in IOS the SVG filter does not render, why is this?

Here is my code (you can run on localhost or google sites):

I have included an image and two buttons to apply the filters separately as a split test - the svg filters work fine in IOS but only for the image - it is as if IOS plays the video in its own special player (even when it plays 'inline' so that it is not full screen), do you know how to switch this off or apply filter over it?

Thank you in advance.

```html
<html lang="en" style="overflow: visible;">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"> 
<style type="text/css">
.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 30px;  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;

  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="overflow: visible;">


<div>
<div id="all" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: visible; min-height: 11vw; min-width: 20vw;">
    <!-- Add a placeholder for the Twitch embed -->
    <div id="whole-embed" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 5px; position: relative; overflow: visible;">
        <div id="twitch-embed-container">
            <div id="twitch-embed"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add buttons below the twitch embed -->
        <div class="playpausecontrols" style="height:30px; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; grid-gap: 20px; position: absolute; bottom: 3%; left: 3%; z-index: 10; border-radius: 5px;"> 
        <i class="material-icons" onclick="playVid();" title="Play" style="color: green; text-align: center; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;">play_arrow</i> 
        <i class="material-icons" onclick="pauseVid();" title="Pause" style="color: green; text-align: center; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;">pause</i> 
        </div>

        <div class="zoomcontrols" style="height:30px; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; grid-gap: 20px; position: absolute; bottom: 3%; right: 3%; z-index: 10; border-radius: 5px;"> 
        <p style="font-size: 0.7vw; color: white; text-align: left; display: inline-block;">PRESS F11 FOR FULL SCREEN</p>
        <i class="material-icons" onclick="zoomin();" title="Bigger" style="color: green; text-align: center; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;">zoom_in</i> 
        <i class="material-icons" onclick="zoomout();" title="Smaller" style="color: green; text-align: center; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;">zoom_out</i> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="testdiv" 
style="position:relative; z-index: 10; background: black url('https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png'); height: 20vw; width: 20vw;">
</div>  
<button id="mybutton">Photo Filter: <span id="mybuttonspan">none</span></button>
<button id="mybutton2">Video Filter: <span id="mybuttonspan2">none</span></button>
</div>

    <!-- Load the Twitch embed script -->
    <script src="https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js"></script>
    <!-- Create a Twitch.Embed object that will render within the "twitch-embed" root element. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        controls: "false",
        autoplay: "false",
        muted: "true",
        theme: "light",
        allowfullscreen: "true",
        channel: "ourchickenlife",
        preload: "auto",
        scrolling: "no",
        parent: ["sites.google.com", document.domain, "gstatic.com", "www.gstatic.com"]
    };
    var player = new Twitch.Player("twitch-embed", options);
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* get element you want to pause and play */
    var vid = document.getElementById("twitch-embed");
    /* call funtion as specified in earlier twitch.js API */
    function pauseVid() {
        player.pause();
    }
    
    function playVid() {
        player.play();
    }
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var divall = document.getElementById("all");
    var factor = 0.2;
    
    function zoomin() {
    var heightname = divall.clientHeight;
    var widthname = divall.clientWidth;
    var addheight = factor * heightname;
    var addwidth = factor * widthname;
    var heightcapture = heightname + addheight;
    var widthcapture = widthname + addwidth;
        divall.style = "height: "+heightcapture+"px; width: "+widthcapture+"px; overflow: visible; min-height: 11vw; min-width: 20vw;";
    }

    function zoomout() {
    var heightname = divall.clientHeight;
    var widthname = divall.clientWidth;
    var addheight = factor * heightname;
    var addwidth = factor * widthname;
    var heightcapture = heightname - addheight;
    var widthcapture = widthname - addwidth;
        divall.style = "height: "+heightcapture+"px; width: "+widthcapture+"px; overflow: visible; min-height: 11vw; min-width: 20vw;";
    }
    </script>
    
    

      <svg id='image' version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>

<filter id="blurEffect">
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4"/>
</filter>

<filter id="turbulence">
<feTurbulence baseFrequency=".01" type="fractalNoise" numOctaves="3" seed="23" stitchTiles="stitch"/>
</filter>

<filter id="blur">
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10,3" result="outBlur"/>
</filter>

<filter id="inverse">
<feComponentTransfer>
<feFuncR type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
<feFuncG type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
<feFuncB type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
</feComponentTransfer>
</filter>

<filter id="convolve">
<feConvolveMatrix order="3" kernelMatrix="1 -1  1 -1 -0.01 -1 1 -1 1" edgeMode="duplicate" result="convo"/>
</filter>

<filter id="convoblur">
<feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="6" result="blur"/>
<feConvolveMatrix order="3" kernelMatrix="1 -1  1 -1 -0.01 -1 1 -1 1" edgeMode="none" result="convo"/>
<feMerge>
<feMergeNode in="blur"/>
<feMergeNode in="convo"/>
</feMerge>
</filter>

<filter id="blackandwhite">
<feColorMatrix values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                                 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                                0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                                0      0      0      1 0"/>
</filter>

<filter id="convolve2">
<feConvolveMatrix filterRes="100 100" style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB" order="3" kernelMatrix="0 -1 0   -1 4 -1   0 -1 0" preserveAlpha="true"/>
</filter>

<filter id="myblur">
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/>
</filter>

<filter id="myconvolve">
<feConvolveMatrix filterRes="100 100" style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB" order="3" kernelMatrix="0 -1 0   -1 4 -1   0 -1 0" preserveAlpha="true"/>
</filter>

<filter id="noir">
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1.5"/>
<feComponentTransfer>
<feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0 .5 1 1"/>
<feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0 .5 1"/>
<feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0"/>
</feComponentTransfer>
</filter>

</defs>
</svg>



<script type="text/javascript"> <!--script one for photo -->

var video = document.getElementById("testdiv"),
 button = document.getElementById("mybutton"),
 current = document.getElementById("mybuttonspan"),
 filters = ['blur','inverse','convolve','convoblur','convolve2','blackandwhite','noir'],
 i = 0;

button.addEventListener('click',function(){
  
  current.innerHTML = filters[i];
  video.style.webkitFilter='url(#'+filters[i]+')';
  video.style.mozFilter='url(#'+filters[i]+')';
  video.style.filter='url(#'+filters[i]+')';
  
  i++;
  
  if (i>=filters.length) i=0;
  
}, false);

</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> <!--script two for video -->

var video1 = document.getElementById("twitch-embed"), <!--experiment changing this to different elements of video player-->
 button1 = document.getElementById("mybutton2"),
 current1 = document.getElementById("mybuttonspan2"),
 filters = ['blur','inverse','convolve','convoblur','convolve2','blackandwhite','noir'],
 i = 0;

button1.addEventListener('click',function(){
  
  current1.innerHTML = filters[i];
  video1.style.webkitFilter='url(#'+filters[i]+')';
  video1.style.mozFilter='url(#'+filters[i]+')';
  video1.style.filter='url(#'+filters[i]+')';
  
  i++;
  
  if (i>=filters.length) i=0;
  
}, false);

</script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't think Safari supports SVG filters on HTML elements. Only Chrome and Firefox do.

Comment: @RobertLongson thank you, ok that's a shame, I wonder if there is an alternative